# Is it legal for a Schengen consulate to refuse issuing a visa to children during school time?

Tags: visas, schengen, minors, czech-republic

A friend of mine was trying to apply for a Czech tourist visa with his wife and two children. He had a letter from the school certifying that the school won't object to their absence. However, the VFS center refused to receive his application for the visa, stating that as a matter of policy the Czech consulate doesn't issue visas to children during the school year.

Are such restrictions legal according to Schengen rules? Could anything be done to force the consulate to process the application?

Comment: Do you mean that the consulate declined to "examine the application" (as the Schengen rules say) in the first place, or that an actual negative decision was reached? Or was filing it denied by a third-party processor (VFS etc)?

Comment: @HenningMalkolm the VFS center declined to accept the application, no actual refusal was issued. The VFS employees mentioned that this is an "informal" policy of the local Czech consulate.

Comment: I would complain to the Czech Embassy directly.

Comment: While not the usual pregnant-bank-accounts crap, this is yet another "borders law" question.  (Subcategory .. "borders law curiosities!")   It's just not a TRAVEL question.

Comment: @Fattie feel free to vote on closing it, mods don't interfere with close votes on their own posts.

Comment: To make this illegal, it would have to be against EU or Czech law. A policy not to examine the application might violate due process regulation. A policy that missing school is considered a strong indication of missing ties to the homeland might be conceivable.

Answer (score 2):

The VFS is not the same as the consulate and they have been known to overstep their bounds.

> Are such restrictions legal according to Schengen rules?

NO

> Could anything be done to force the consulate to process the
>   application?

Reach out directly to the embassy.

Comment: Can you reference your "NO"? I cannot immediately find anywhere in the Schengen rule apparatus that would unambiguously forbid a Member State from having such a policy.